# Как посмотреть код через дизассемблер ildasm? Выдает ошибку

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015. Хочу посмотреть код через дизассемблер.
Ildasm выдает ошибку: отсутствует допустимый заголовок CLR, поэтому дизассемблирование невозможно.
Кто-нибудь знает, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Поправить тот самый заголовок? Без конкретных файлов - гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: А может, ваша программа — нативная программа наC++, а не .NET-сборка?